# Which combinatorics formula should I use for this question?

Tags: combinatorics

I know about four combinatorics formulas:

$$\begin{array}{lcc}
& \text{with ordering} & \text{without ordering} \\[5pt]
\text{with replacement} & n^k & \binom{n+k-1}{k} \\[5pt]
\text{without replacement} & \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} & \underbrace{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,k!} = \binom{n}{k}}_{\small\text{binomial coefficient}}
\end{array}$$

This is the question I’m struggling with:

> There are 9 women, 5 men, and 3 children standing at a row. What is the chance that 2 women are not after each other?

It should be possible to solve this question with one of the formulas quoted above, but which one should I use?

Comment: If the question is asking for the chance that no two women are consecutive, you can count how many ways to arrange the 5 men and 3 children in a row, and then count how many ways you can put the women in the remaining gaps (to get the number of favorable outcomes).

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 9 women, and 8 "non-women". There is obviously only one way to not have women standing next to each other:

W N W N W N W N W N W N W N W N W

where the W's are women and the N's are not. For your restriction that women can't touch each other, there is obviously only one place to put the women. You now have 8 spots for the men and children. There are $8\choose5$ ways to pick spots to place the men, and ${3\choose3}=1$ remaining ways for the children. So there are ${8\choose5}$ ways to organise them without women touching. If there are no restrictions, there are $17\choose9$ ways to pick spots for the women, $8\choose5$ remaining for the men, and ${3\choose3}=1$ way for the rest of the children. Hence the probability that the women don't touch is 
$$\frac{8\choose5}{{17\choose9}{8\choose5}}=\frac1{17\choose9}=\frac1{24310}$$
Note that the order you do it in above is irrelevant; you chould as easily have assigned spots to the men, children, and women in that order, and you'd have the same result.

Alternatively, you can reach the same result with permutations instead. Since the women and non-women are locked in a particular pattern when women can touch, only how you organise them matters. There are $9!$ ways to organise the women without touching (shuffling which woman is which above), and $8!$ ways for the non-women. Hence $9! \cdot8!$ ways that the women can't touch. Without this restriction, there are obviously $17!$ ways to organise the group in a line. Hence the odds are
$$\frac{9!8!}{17!}=\frac1{17\choose9}=\frac1{24310}$$

One more way, just count the position of the women. If there are 17 empty spots in the line, the diagram above makes it obvious there is exactly $1$ way to position the women so they don't touch. The non-women fill the rest. If they can touch, there $17\choose 9$ combinations of spots to place the women. The non-women once more fill the rest. Hence the odds are 
$$\frac1{17\choose9}=\frac1{24310}$$

In general, when you need a probability, how you count doesn't matter, as long as you are consistent. In the first, we counted combinations, in the second we counted permuations, in the third, we count spots for women. All obtained the same results. Count the way you feel most comfortable, or most convenient to the problem when you need a probability.